# CSS: how to select parent's sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML in my page.

```html
<ul id="detailsList">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="showCheckbox" />
        <label for="showCheckbox">Show Details</label>
    </li>
    <li>content ...</li>
    <li>content ...</li>
    <li>content ...</li>
    <li>content ...</li>
    <li>content ...</li>
</ul>
```

I am unable to change this HTML. I have hidden all LI's with the exception of the first by using the following CSS

```css
ul#detailsList li:nth-child(1n+2) {
    display:none;
}
```

So far so good. What I want to do now is to show those hidden LI's when the the checkbox is ticked, using pure CSS. My best attempt so far is

```css
ul#detailsList li input#showCheckbox:checked + li {
    display:block;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as the **+ li** will only select LI's immediately after the checkbox (i.e. siblings), not siblings of the parent.

Is this even possible?

Comment: CSS does not allow you to select parent elements. Only sibling and child elements are supported.

Comment: simple answer no - css does not have a prarent selector

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `:has()`:

```css
ul#detailsList:has(> li > input#showCheckbox:checked) > li {
    display: block;
}
```

Please note, though, that [browser support for :has()](https://caniuse.com/css-has) is not very good yet.

---

<strike>You cannot do that with CSS but</strike>

You can try using jQuery

```
$("#showCheckbox").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings().show();
});
```

Comment: That is what I figured, but thought I would ask just in case. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: is it possible to get a MWE with :has? I cannot seem to get it to work...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with CSS alone, you need to use `javascript` for this. As You need to catch the change event of the checkbox.